# How to parse JSON object with $.ajax() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to parse a JSON object (not stored on a file) by using `$.ajax()` method but it is not functioning. What am I doing wrong?

```
var painting = [
        {
        "title": "Boardwalk 5",
        "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
        "image": "ap1.jpg",
        "price": 850
        },
        {
        "title": "A Lasting Piece",
        "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
        "image": "ap2.jpg",
        "price": 450
        },
        {
        "title": "Surf at High Tide",
        "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
        "image": "ap3.jpg",
        "price": 950
        },
        {
        "title": "The Games We Play",
        "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
        "image": "ap4.jpg",
        "price": 850
        }
      ];
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'painting',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: jsonParser
});

});

function jsonParser(json) {
    $.getJSON(painting, function(data){
        $.each(painting, function(k,v){
            var title = v.title;
            var price = v.price;
            $('#container').append('<div class="painting"><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing an Array instead of a URL to `$.getJSON`? And you seem to be ignoring the `json` returned form the `$.ajax` call. Why is that?

Comment: What do you expect `$.getJSON(painting` to do?  `$.getJSON` is a AJAX method.  `painting` is *already* an object, it's *NOT* a JSON string!  Just get rid of `$.getJSON(painting,`.

Comment: Ok I got confused! is this "painting" JSON or Not!? As far as I know it is not Javascript Object because of having "" in both key and value pair. so wjy are you guys saying to not use the Ajax method!

Comment: @user1760110: You mean the `painting` variable? No, it's not referencing JSON data. If it were JSON data, it would be simple text that represents a data structure. Sort of like XML is textual data representing a data structure. Within your program, the `painting` variable will be referencing a JavaScript Array of Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need .ajax to parse json that is in variable?

Have you tried only this:

```
$.each(painting, function(k,v){
  var title = v.title;
  var price = v.price;
  $('#container').append('<div class="painting"><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
});
```

If I understood you good, you do not need .getjson and .ajax since those are Ajax calls to retrieve external data?

Comment: *"to parse json that is in variable"* It's not even JSON, it's an array of objects.

Comment: True that, but in the spirit of the question, it "looks" like json.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he's trying to get a json from a file ?

Maybe painting.json or painting is his json file.
that'll explain why he's using ajax and getJson.

You have to understand that  $.getJSON uses $.ajax.

So :

```
var painting = [
    {
    "title": "Boardwalk 5",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap1.jpg",
    "price": 850
    },
    {
    "title": "A Lasting Piece",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap2.jpg",
    "price": 450
    },
    {
    "title": "Surf at High Tide",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap3.jpg",
    "price": 950
    },
    {
    "title": "The Games We Play",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap4.jpg",
    "price": 850
    }
  ];
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON('painting.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(k,v){
            var title = v.title;
            var price = v.price;
            $('#container').append('<div class="painting"><br/><div class="title">' + title  + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
        });

     });
});
```

is enough

Comment: Thanks Su4P, Honestly it was captured from a file json data but as you can see I have updated it to be formatted as jason object.The reason that I asked this question is what if I have all of this data stored inside a variable? Then how I can achive them?

Comment: You can archive the data in the database as json if you are in php you can do json_encode($_POST) to have json again or if you want you can store them as serialize array. You also can store the data in a file but I wouldn't recommand it. Either way check json_encode and serialize function. If you are not in PHP there are equivalent in most of the language. As my guess was right maybe you can vote up ?